# How to check in a Rules Condition if an Ubercart product is out of order?

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart

There isn't a good support for "out of order" in Ubercart for Drupal. I'm trying to fix that with the Rules module.

I'm trying to add a rule that disables the product after the stock is updated, using Rules event *After updating existing content of type Product*.
I want to disable the product that is sold out (stock = 0).

Here is an export of the rule I have so far:

```
{ "rules_product_sold_out_check" : {
    "LABEL" : "Product sold out check",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--product" : { "bundle" : "product" } },
    "DO" : []
  }
}
```

But the stock isn't a field of the node. How can I select that field within a Rules Condition? I have no idea how to use that in the Rules module as a data selector.

> The data to be compared, specified by using a data selector, e.g.
>   "node:author:name".

I'm using the stock also in a view. This is what I use there (export-code-view to show the fieldnames / structure).

```
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['stock']['id'] = 'stock';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['stock']['table'] = 'uc_product_stock';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['stock']['field'] = 'stock';
```

I use **Ubercart 7.x-3.10** (with Stock 7.x-3.10), **Drupal 7**, **Rules 7.x-2.10**

Comment: Operation is the same as Rules Event.. I don't have any rules yet for the stock. I only want to disable the product that is sold out (stock = 0).. I added the export. But I need the condition before I can add an action..

Answer (score 0):

As per the UC issue about "[Stock transaction should be more flexible through Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart/issues/1514756)" (from 6 years ago, status "needs work" ...), it seems that at this time trying to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for such "out of order" situations may not be a good idea.

You may want to try to use the [Ubercart Out of stock Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_out_of_stock) module instead. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Out of stock notification for
>   [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart).
>
> It uses ajax and jquery and asks the server for available stock and
>   replaces the 'Add to cart' button with some configurable HTML.
>
> ...
>
> It also provides server-side validation so this module can prevent the
>   addition of out of stock items even if JS is disabled or if the user
>   clicks on an "Add to cart" button too quickly.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I'm using Ubercart now for 3 months. But all the additional modules for UC I used so far are very buggy (like UC discounts, UC VAT ...)..